# How to parse JSON array using Jersey Rest Webservices and save to table using Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am getting Json array from mobile side and want to parse the Json in server side using Java and jersey and Gson. I am sending the JSON array in POST method from iOS. I want to consume the json but stuck on how do i save the json data in Java class. This is the structure of my Json array`entities:{"stores":[{"tills":[{"name":"b1 till1"}],"name":"b1 store"},{"tills":[{"name":"b2 till2"}],"name":"b2 store"}],"name":"B mart"}
entities:{"stores":[{"tills":[{"name":"c1 till1"}],"name":"c1 store"},{"tills":[{"name":"c2 till2"}],"name":"c2 store"}],"name":"C mart"}
name:Dmart`

Comment: A similar question has been answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073624/how-to-convert-json-objects-to-pojo-from-gson

Comment: my json array response from mobile side is different i want parse in following format.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to do simply like this:
This is a code snippet i used in one of my test-applications

To parse JSON you need in my example the [GSON-Library](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
@Path("/FriendsList")
public class RestWebServicesAPI{

@POST
@Path("/friends")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Friends saveFriendList(final String json){
    Gson gs = new Gson();
    Friends [] n = gs.fromJson(json, Friends [].class);

}
//ALTERNATIVE
@POST
    @Path("/friends")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Friends saveFriendList(final Friends[] friends){


    }
```