# Data retrieve in android from JSON parsing in GET method

Tags: android, json, list, arraylist

How to get email or mobile from GET method in retrofit android

i'm trying more then time but my app crash so how to get these value.

JSON response.

```
{
    "statuscode": 200,
    "status": "true",
    "applied_jobs": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 44,
            "job_post_id": 12,
            "resume": "241115637974717139.doc",
            "created_at": "2019-07-22 12:11:11",
            "updated_at": "2019-07-22 12:11:11",
            "posted_job": {
                "id": 12,
                "user_id": 44,
                "email": "appt@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "9712112332",
                "company_name": "Appt Tech",
                "title": "Java Developer",
                "description": "Java, Android, XML",
                "no_of_position": 5,
                "job_requirment": "Experience",
                "country_id": 1,
                "state_id": 2,
                "city_id": 2,
                "location": "Noida",
                "photo": "242415637879146897.png",
                "status": 1,
                "created_at": "2019-07-22 09:31:54",
                "updated_at": "2019-07-22 09:31:54"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

Retrofit Interface

```
    @GET("retrieve/get_applied_job?user_id=44")
    Call<ListAllAppliedJobs> getAllAppliedJobs();
```

I just want get email or mobile values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: post ListAllAppliedJobs class

Comment: Either change the response from Backend Server or you have to make POJO and retrieve value.

Comment: You have to get the object containing the applied job list... Then access the array from that object.

Comment: post the code where the retrofit instance is created

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ use this website to create model classes. Then use it for access email and mobile. If you are creating the api, then send only the required values.

Comment: Thanks but i want , how to get email mobile . like adapter or main activity with all files. Model i've already created but problem is that json parsing

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your json response to a pojo class to retrieve the value, 
you can convert it using two ways :

1. use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org to convert directly
2. Please refer [How to convert JSON objects to POJO from Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073624/how-to-convert-json-objects-to-pojo-from-gson)

and then retrieve the email from the email or the phone objects in the pojo class.

Comment: Thanks but i want , how to get email mobile . like adapter or main activity with all files. Model i've already created but problem is that json parsing

Answer (score 0):

@Jude Osbert k is Right

Place the below code it works  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ it works 100%

```
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class AppliedJob {


    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    @Expose
    private String updatedAt;
    @SerializedName("posted_job")
    @Expose
    private PostedJob postedJob;

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public PostedJob getPostedJob() {
        return postedJob;
    }

    public void setPostedJob(PostedJob postedJob) {
        this.postedJob = postedJob;
    }

}

import java.util.List;
        import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
        import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ListAllAppliedJobs {

    @SerializedName("statuscode")
    @Expose
    private Integer statuscode;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("applied_jobs")
    @Expose
    private List<AppliedJob> appliedJobs = null;

    public Integer getStatuscode() {
        return statuscode;
    }

    public void setStatuscode(Integer statuscode) {
        this.statuscode = statuscode;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<AppliedJob> getAppliedJobs() {
        return appliedJobs;
    }

    public void setAppliedJobs(List<AppliedJob> appliedJobs) {
        this.appliedJobs = appliedJobs;
    }

}


import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
        import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class PostedJob {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer userId;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("mobile")
    @Expose
    private String mobile;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks 
but i want , how to get email mobile . like adapter or main activity with all files.
Model i've already created but problem is that json parsing.

Comment: List<AppliedJob> appliedJobs = response.body().getAppliedJobs();
    for(int i= 0 ; i< appliedJobs.size(); i++){
       appliedJobs.get(i).getPostedJob().getEmail();
    }