# JSON parsing of nested objects inside Arraytypes

Tags: java, json, parsing, jsonparser

I have a Json response obtained after a RESTAPI call to a platform. The Json file has a structure as follows:

```
{
    "next" : "https://XXXX"
    "self"  : "https://XXXX"
    "managedObjects":[
        {
            "AP" : {
                "self" : "https://YYYY"
                "references":[
                ]
            }
            "owner": "ABC"
            "types" : {
                "name":"XXX",
                "place":"XXX",
                "self":"https://XXXX",
                "version":"2.8.0"
            }
            "name" : "XYZ"
            "Protocol":{
                "IOT":{
                       "protocol":"SOAP",
                       "informationModel":"XX2"
                    },
                    "IIOT":{
                       "protocol":"OPC UA",
                       "informationModel":"REF"
                    }
            }   
        }
    ]
}
```

I have written a java program to obtain the response of the call. I do not seem to understand a simpler mechanism to parse this JSON. The value for "managedObjects" has multiple values, and each of them is nested.

I would like to have a map which has the name and type information.

Could anyone provide me any guidance here?Would be Much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68952106/16497617

Comment: Do i have to create individual property elements for everything? I mean that could dynamically change

Comment: try with `jackson` dependencies